# Uniform convergence of differentiable funciton

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

My question was brought up when I'm trying to understand a proof of following theorem.

$\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of differentiable functions on (a,b). Suppose that $\{f_n(c)\}$ converges for some $c\in(a,b)$ and $\{f'_n\}$ converges uniformly on $(a,b)$. Then $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to a differentiable function $f$ on $(a,b)$

Let $g_n= \frac{f_n(x)-f_n(c)}{x-c}$ if $x\neq c$ ,  $g_n(x)=f'(x)$ if $x=c$
Then $\{g_n\}$ converges uniformly on (a,b).
and $f_n(x)=f_n(c)+g_n(x)(x-c)$ for all $x \in R$

Since $g_n$ converges uniformly on $(a,b)$ and $f_n(c)$ converges by assumption, $f_n$ converges pointwise on $(a,b)$ trivially.  I have some questions at this point.
Does $\{f_n\}$ converge uniformly on (a,b)?
I guess that it does not hold. 
I showed  $\{f_n\}$ converge uniformly on $[e,f] \subset (a,b)$ instead.
But I don't know how to show $\{f_n\}$  may not converge uniformly on open interval (a,b)